# How can I populate referenced Objects in a MongoDB Atlas query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongoose-populate

I have a collection in MongoDB Atlas that I've created using an app I'm building. The collection is called "timeRecords", and each document has an an "experience" field, which is an ObjectID that references an experience document in the "experience" collections.

In node.js, I populate this by executing a search query then chain .populate() to the end of the query. My question is whether there's a way to do this via the UI on MongoDB Atlas' website?

[image]

I've tried using the "More Options" but I can't figure this out. I want to go into the database and search for documents without needing to know the exact object ID. For example, each experience is categorized by "easy", "intermediate" and "expert", I want to search by all "experience.expert" documents, except the "experience" field isn't populated.

Comment: aggregation with lookup? populate is a mongoose thing if im correct

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/0FsvuPB2vzr

Comment: You're right - I've been using mongoose in node.js, so that's where that came from. I'll need to look into aggregate + lookup...never used that before, but I see the aggregate tab now in Atlas, so I bet that's how to do it, just need to figure out the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the playground - that's exactly what I needed. Thank you for the easy help with documentation! If you want to throw it in an answer, I'll accept :)

Comment: aggregation is like a pipeline. you can have sequential stages. so it takes an array of stages. here the first and only stage is a lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`populate` is mongooses specific thing so you won't be able to use it in mongo shell

quoting the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate)

> **Populate**
>
> MongoDB has the join-like $lookup aggregation operator in versions >=
> 3.2. Mongoose has a more powerful alternative called populate(), which lets you reference documents in other collections.

for your case you can use the aggregation tab in atlas.

for example like

```js
db.timeRecords.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "experience",  //collection to populate
      localField: "experience", //local field you want to match
      foreignField: "_id", //field to match of the collection you are going to populate
      as: "experienceData" // populated field stored in this field
    }
  }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0FsvuPB2vzr)